# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS not recognising external DVD drive

Tags: usb, hardware, dvd

since upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from 15.10, I've been having trouble loading DVDs onto my machine from my external disc drive (the drive is a Lite-On eTAU108 manufactured back in May of 2010 if that info helps). I had also entered `sudo lshw -C disk` into the terminal and got this:

```
  *-cdrom                 
   description: DVD-RAM writer
   product: eTAU108   1
   vendor: Slimtype
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@68:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/cdrom
   logical name: /dev/cdrw
   logical name: /dev/dvd
   logical name: /dev/dvdrw
   logical name: /dev/sr0
   version: EL46
   capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
   configuration: status=ready
 *-medium
      physical id: 0
      logical name: /dev/cdrom
```

after that, I entered `sudo dmesg` into the terminal and got this:

```
[ 6472.043056] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 49 using xhci_hcd
[ 6472.236495] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1c6b, idProduct=a222
[ 6472.236517] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6472.236524] usb 1-2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 6472.236529] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: USB2.0 External
[ 6472.236535] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 2010042000000051239
[ 6472.237751] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6472.241377] scsi host68: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[ 6473.262959] scsi 68:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Slimtype eTAU108   1      EL46 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 6473.328635] sr 68:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda pop-up
[ 6473.328955] sr 68:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 6473.329110] sr 68:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[ 6545.854840] sr 68:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6545.854853] sr 68:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 6545.854864] sr 68:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 6545.854874] sr 68:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 02 00
[ 6545.854880] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4096
[ 6545.918861] sr 68:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6545.918871] sr 68:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 6545.918882] sr 68:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 6545.918888] sr 68:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 02 00
[ 6545.918892] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4096
[ 6545.918899] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 512, async page read
[ 6580.841506] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
```

I often use my external DVD drive to watch movies/TV shows as it is the only way to watch them on my computer aside from downloading or streaming.

Comment: Any luck with this? I removed the optical from an old machine to populate all the SATA channels with hard drives, but now I can't get it to recognize a burner. It sees a blank DVD-R when I insert it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error because region code was not set correctly.

e.g., install and run 'regionset'

```
sudo apt-get install regionset
regionset

jen@suumachine:~$ regionset
regionset version 0.1 -- reads/sets region code on DVD drives
Current Region Code settings:
RPC Phase: II
type: NONE
vendor resets available: 4
user controlled changes resets available: 5
drive plays discs from region(s):, mask=0xFF

Would you like to change the region setting of your drive? [y/n]:y
```

type: NONE means region code is not set. In my case problem was resolved after I set regioncode. Note that the disc have to be in the drive to run regionset(!).

Before trying this you might want to check that other relevant packages are installed, most importantly libdvdcss2.

```
dpkg -l libdvd-pkg libdvdread4 libdvdnav4 libdvdcss2
jen@suumachine:~$ dpkg -l libdvd-pkg libdvdread4 libdvdnav4 libdvdcss2
ii  libdvd-pkg          1.4.0-1-1      all            DVD-Video playing library - installer
ii  libdvdcss2          1.4.0-1        amd64          <insert up to 60 chars description>
ii  libdvdnav4:amd64    5.0.3-1        amd64          DVD navigation library
ii  libdvdread4:amd64   5.0.3-1        amd64          library for reading DVDs
```

`
The first three are installed as any other package,

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4 libdvdnav4 libdvd-pkg
```

libdvdcss2 is downloaded as source, build and installed by libdvd-pkg. If it is not already installed try the following,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

Lastly, you might want to check that you have read (and usually write) access on sr0,

```
ls -la /dev/sr0

jen@suumachine:~$ ls -la /dev/sr0 brw-rw-rw-+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Okt 22 18:49 /dev/sr0
```

These rights are usually granted to the 'cdrom' group. You would want to add your user to the 'cdrom' group.